# Visual Studio 2010 C++: Hard coded strings leading to slow compile times

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So I have a file that is taking a few minutes to compile, and have narrowed it down to the fact it contains, roughly, a few thousand lines of hard-coded strings being passed into a Qt function. The file was auto generated from another source, so the strings represent enumeration values to be placed into Qt controls for selection. Example:

Method A

```
mywidget->insertItem("My value 1, string representation of enum value 1");
mywidget->insertItem("My value 2, string representation of enum value 2");
mywidget->insertItem("My value 3, string representation of enum value 3");
```

...

I then commented out a section (around 1000 lines) of this code, and replaced with:

Method B

```
const QString myValues[] = { "My value 1, string representation of enum     value 1", "My value 2, string representation of enum value 2", "My value 3,   string representation of enum value 3", ... };

for( int item = 0; item < 1000; ++item ){
    mywidget->insertItem(myValues[item]);
}
```

method B compiled significantly quicker. Why? I have tried with Optimization on/off, while optimization on is longer, even when off, compiling takes a long time with Method A.

Edit: Yes, I thought the number of lines would effect compile time, however I compared the time to another file that was about half the amount of lines of code (with only a few of the hard coded string lines) and it compiled significantly quicker. It seems the file in question took exponentially longer.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Optimization has nothing to do with how the compiler parses the code, it's only about code generation.

Comment: 1000 lines vs 3 lines, 3 lines will be faster to compile.

Comment: @YOU: I don't think that OP could have hoped for a better answer than that. You may as well post it IMO.

Comment: I clarified in my Edit, should have been in the OP. Note, the const QString array I declare, will have 1000 elements added to it.

Comment: I've two guesses: 

a) translating the method insertItem() into machine code takes some time. In Case 1 it is done 1000 times, in case 2 it's done once.

b) In case 1 the compiler has to switch tasks a lot: translate, copy, translate, copy, translate, ... . In case 2 its just copy once, translate loop once, translate method once.

Comment: @YOU I think this doesn't answer the question. The question is why is that so? Note that the code is nearly equally long because Method B has a very long array declaration.

Comment: @Tobi, thanks for pointing out, I missed the  array declaration part, but I still think array declaration is easy to parse (parser should able to figure what should be on next token) and few way to optimize than, many class method calls. I am not answering question, because I dont write gcc or even c parser

Comment: I used the word 'lines' which was easy to pick, but better word could be 'tokens'. also looking up the class, and looking up its method would take time, but parsing a string array dont have to look up anything